# Angular - close open modal dialog programmatically when another modal dialog opens

Tags: angular, angular-material

In our application we have an auto logout functionality which presents a pop-up after X minutes of inactivity. If the user doesn't interact with a button (say Continue Session), we automatically log the user out.
Now if an other pop-up (Popup A) pertaining to other features in present in the screen, and the user goes afk, both Popup A and the autologout pop-up show up, and if the user is automatically logged out then Popup A is still present in the screen. Is there anyway to close an opened popup programmatically once the Autologout pop-up is presented?

Answer (score 1):

There can be a way that I can think of right now, Close all the Dialog which are being open. We have done the same in our application.

You can take the advantage of the Dialog API:

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

export class TestClass {

constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialog) {
}

closeAllPopUp()
{ //You should call this when you close the Inactive screen Dialog popup
  this.dialogRef.closeAll();
}

}
```